# Upload files from raspberry pi to Mega cloud using megatools

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, raspberry-pi, cloud

I have been trying to upload files from debian machine (raspberrypi) to mega cloud storage via CLI.

I have created the `.megarc` file in my home directory in the following format

```
[Login]
Username = ******@gmail.com
Password = ***********
```

I getting the following error

```
$ megadf -h
ERROR: Can't login to mega.nz: API call 'us' failed: Server returned error EEXPIRED
```

Let me know if there are any fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I could find is as follows:-

Instead of installing and using `megatools` package from raspbian/debian package manager, download the installer package from https://mega.nz/cmd.

update and upgrade using:-

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
```

Install the downloaded `.deb` file

```
# dpkg -i megacmd-Raspbian_9.0_armhf.deb
```

Login to the Mega account using:-

```
# mega-login username password
```